# Как в php сделать reverse для объекта?

Tags: php, html

Есть код, нужно вывести элементы в обратном порядке:

```
$doctors_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $doctors_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<ul class="el-grid <?php if($doctors_layout_style == 'nogap') echo 'nogap-cols'; ?>" data-layout-mode="<?php echo esc_attr($doctors_layout); ?>" data-gap="<?php echo esc_attr($doctors_layout_style); ?>" data-pagination="<?php echo esc_attr($doctors_pagination); ?>" >

<?php
while ( $doctors_query->have_posts() ) : $doctors_query->the_post();

$doctor_department = _get_field('gg_doctor_department');
$doctor_department = array_reverse($doctor_department);
$department_array = array();

foreach ( $doctor_department as $department ) {
    $department_array[] = $department->post_name;
}
?>

    <li class="isotope-item col-xs-12 col-md-<?php echo esc_attr(floor( 12 / $doctors_columns )); ?> col-sm-<?php echo esc_attr(floor( 12 / $doctors_columns )); ?> <?php echo esc_attr(implode(' ', $department_array)); ?>" >
        <?php get_template_part( 'parts/doctors/part','doctor' ); ?>
    </li><!-- // doctors item column -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

`$doctor_department` это объект.

Пробовал:

```
foreach($doctor_department as $key => $value) {
    print "$key => $value\n";
}
```

Ошибка.

Если так:

```
$doctor_department = array_reverse($doctor_department);
```

Ничего не происходит.

Подскажите, как вывести в обратном порядке?

Comment: Что в объекте? Трудно написать решение не имея значений объекта

Comment: var_dump($doctor_department) выложите

Answer (score 1):

Есть 2 варианта.

1. Выводить все элементы самому.

   `echo $doctor_department->nameRu;
   echo $doctor_department->nameEn;`
2. В объекте сделать свойство в котором указать порядок рендерига свойств

   `class DoctorDepartment {
       public $renderMap = [
           'nameRu',
           'nameEn',
       ];
   }
   $doctor_department = new DoctorDepartment();
   foreach ($doctor_department as $propertyName) {
       echo $doctor_department->{propertyName};
   }`